# LWC Datatable - Multi-level Headers

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, header

Is it possible to format multi-tiered headers with LWC `lightning-datatable` component? I do not see anything in documentation, and I've tried passing in nested array of headers into `columns` attribute. But no luck.

An example is linked on [W3 Org website](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/irregular/#table-with-two-tier-headers). And I've attached a screenshot for clarity.

Any suggestions or workarounds?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not supported. The lightning-datatable is designed after SLDS, which does not have an allowance for multiple header rows or cells that span more than one column. You'd have to roll your own table instead.